# Appending files in a folder using R

Tags: r, syntax, append, data-management

i am appending 100 files in a folder with a delimiter "|". Below is the code used. I am getting an error whichi am not able to debug,

```
file_list <- list.files()

dataset <- ldply(file_list, read.table, header=TRUE,  sep="|")
```

ERROR - Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 284 did not have 12 elements

Please help me on this who have experience around this.

Comment: You could try with `ldply(file_list, read.table, header=TRUE, fill = TRUE, sep="|")` (the message is quite clear I would say)

Comment: Hey hi,
I tried the argument fill = TRUE, it ran for a while and gave me the below error,



    Error in FUN(X[[29L]], ...) : more columns than column names
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  EOF within quoted string
2: In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  EOF within quoted string

I got the same error 10 times.